# Manage transactions within a spring transactional test case.

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I have a test case which does an insert for a domain object. Now within the domain object one of the fields "deploymentType" if it is not set then postgres has an default which it will populate it with as production.

I want to test this in my spring unit test of the default is set when i do an insert with the deploymentType set to null and postgres taking care of it.

My Test case extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests and has been annotated with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
```

The unit test case is as follows.

```
@Test
public void createCustomerWithSite() {

   this.customerService.createCustomerSite(TestData.makeCustomerSite(this.customer, "test-alias"));

    final List<CustomerSite> list = this.customerService.findCustomerSites(this.customer.getId());
    assertThat(list.size(), is(1));
    final CustomerSite cs = list.get(0);
    assertThat(cs.getClusterDeploymentType(), is(ClusterDeploymentType.PRODUCTION));
}
```

Now since the test is transactional the commit never takes place and hence when i get back the domain object i see the "deploymentType" is null and test fails.

So in such case when i want to test the db behavior in unit test, i guess i need to get access to transactionManager in middle of test , commit the transaction. The start a new Transaction and get the domain object from db and then check if the default value has been set by db while inserting.

Like :

```
       this.customerService.createCustomerSite(TestData.makeCustomerSite(this.customer, "test-alias"));
       TransactionManager tm = getTransactionManager();
       tm.commit(); // the default type will be insterted in db and be visible in next transaction.
       tm.beginTransaction(); 

        final List<CustomerSite> list = this.customerService.findCustomerSites(this.customer.getId());
        assertThat(list.size(), is(1));
        final CustomerSite cs = list.get(0);
        assertThat(cs.getClusterDeploymentType(), is(ClusterDeploymentType.PRODUCTION));
```

How do i get access to transaction manager in a unit test which is transactional.  Is this the right way ?

Comment: Since you are doing commits to db during your test, this is more of an integration test, and not a Unit Test.

Answer (score 0):

You only need access to the EntityManager/SessionFactory (depending on what you use) and simply class flush.

Then use another means of querying the database (a JdbcTemplate) to retrieve the row from the database and check if everything is correct. You don't want to test by the same means you put something in the database as you are only testing the first (or second level) cache that way.